# adding multiple event listeners to one element

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

So my dilemma is that I don't want to write the same code twice. Once for the click event and another for the `touchstart` event.

Here is the original code:

```
document.getElementById('first').addEventListener('touchstart', function(event) {
    do_something();
    });

document.getElementById('first').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    do_something(); 
    });
```

How can I compact this? There HAS to be a simpler way!

Comment: ES2020?! I wish.

Comment: Still not available in ES2022 ?

Comment: ES2022?! Still a wish.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Maybe you can use a helper function like this:

```
// events and args should be of type Array
function addMultipleListeners(element,events,handler,useCapture,args){
  if (!(events instanceof Array)){
    throw 'addMultipleListeners: '+
          'please supply an array of eventstrings '+
          '(like ["click","mouseover"])';
  }
  //create a wrapper to be able to use additional arguments
  var handlerFn = function(e){
    handler.apply(this, args && args instanceof Array ? args : []);
  }
  for (var i=0;i<events.length;i+=1){
    element.addEventListener(events[i],handlerFn,useCapture);
  }
}

function handler(e) {
  // do things
};

// usage
addMultipleListeners(
    document.getElementById('first'),
    ['touchstart','click'],
    handler,
    false);
```

[**Edit nov. 2020**] This answer is pretty old. The way I solve this nowadays is by using an `actions` object where handlers are specified per event type, a `data-attribute` for an element to indicate which action should be executed on it  and one generic document wide handler method (so [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)).

```js
const firstElemHandler = (elem, evt) =>
  elem.textContent = `You ${evt.type === "click" ? "clicked" : "touched"}!`;
const actions = {
  click: {
    firstElemHandler,
  },
  touchstart: {
    firstElemHandler,
  },
  mouseover: {
    firstElemHandler: elem => elem.textContent = "Now ... click me!",
    outerHandling: elem => {
      console.clear();
      console.log(`Hi from outerHandling, handle time ${
        new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}`);
    },
  }
};

Object.keys(actions).forEach(key => document.addEventListener(key, handle));

function handle(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target.closest("[data-action]");
  return origin &&
    actions[evt.type] &&
    actions[evt.type][origin.dataset.action] &&
    actions[evt.type][origin.dataset.action](origin, evt) ||
    true;
}
```

```css
[data-action]:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div data-action="outerHandling">
  <div id="first" data-action="firstElemHandler">
    <b>Hover, click or tap</b>
  </div>
  this is handled too (on mouse over)
</div>
```

Comment: Warning: The event is unavailable in the handle function. I fixed this bug https://pastebin.com/raw/Lrcdv1ws

Answer (score 238):

I thought some might find this approach useful; it could be applied to any similarly repetitive code:

ES6

```
['click','ontouchstart'].forEach( evt => 
    element.addEventListener(evt, dosomething, false)
);
```

ES5

```
['click','ontouchstart'].forEach( function(evt) {
    element.addEventListener(evt, dosomething, false);
});
```

Comment: But how to target specific selectors ?

Comment: you can use something like: 
    document.querySelectorAll(selectors).forEach((element) => { ... });

Comment: When I try to use this, the function I write where you have written "dosomething" fires upon loading the page. Why is that? Even though the full line is: ````burgerElement.addEventListener(event, alertFunction(), false)```` and 'burgerelement' is ````var burgerElement = document.querySelector('.burger');````

Comment: you are executing alertFunction(), and assigning the return value of that (which is undefined) to the event handler.  don't execute the function (with () ), just pass the function name/reference to the eventListener function.  Notice in my example, dosomething does not have () after it.

Comment: ^^^^ The above comment is really important, leaving off the () lets the function lay dormant in the event listener until the event occurs, then the eventlistener basically calls the function for you....I know I am rehashing the above, but really easy to pull your hair out over....

Comment: what value should we pass to variavle evt?

Comment: Ahmad, the forEach method of the Array will automatically pass in each of the array elements into the function for you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Works brilliantly to avoid having multiple event listeners to fire off the same function due to different events.

Answer (score 43):

You can just define a function and pass it. Anonymous functions are not special in any way, all functions can be passed around as values.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('first');

elem.addEventListener('touchstart', handler, false);
elem.addEventListener('click', handler, false);

function handler(event) {
    do_something();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. I needed to have multiple Textarea's to do a live preview and your code allowed me to do HTML and CSS all in one shot. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

For large numbers of events this might help:

```
var element = document.getElementById("myId");
var myEvents = "click touchstart touchend".split(" ");
var handler = function (e) {
    do something
};

for (var i=0, len = myEvents.length; i < len; i++) {
    element.addEventListener(myEvents[i], handler, false);
}
```

**Update 06/2017:**

Now that new language features are more widely available you could simplify adding a limited list of events that share one listener.

```
const element = document.querySelector("#myId");

function handleEvent(e) {
    // do something
}
// I prefer string.split because it makes editing the event list slightly easier

"click touchstart touchend touchmove".split(" ")
    .map(name => element.addEventListener(name, handleEvent, false));
```

If you want to handle lots of events and have different requirements per listener you can also [pass an object](https://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/handleevent) which most people tend to forget.

```
const el = document.querySelector("#myId");

const eventHandler = {
    // called for each event on this element
    handleEvent(evt) {
        switch (evt.type) {
            case "click":
            case "touchstart":
                // click and touchstart share click handler
                this.handleClick(e);
                break;
            case "touchend":
                this.handleTouchend(e);
                break;
            default:
                this.handleDefault(e);
        }
    },
    handleClick(e) {
        // do something
    },
    handleTouchend(e) {
        // do something different
    },
    handleDefault(e) {
        console.log("unhandled event: %s", e.type);
    }
}

el.addEventListener(eventHandler);
```

**Update 05/2019:**

```
const el = document.querySelector("#myId");

const eventHandler = {
    handlers: {
        click(e) {
            // do something
        },
        touchend(e) {
            // do something different
        },
        default(e) {
            console.log("unhandled event: %s", e.type);
        }
    },
    // called for each event on this element
    handleEvent(evt) {
        switch (evt.type) {
            case "click":
            case "touchstart":
                // click and touchstart share click handler
                this.handlers.click(e);
                break;
            case "touchend":
                this.handlers.touchend(e);
                break;
            default:
                this.handlers.default(e);
        }
    }
}

Object.keys(eventHandler.handlers)
    .map(eventName => el.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler))
```

Comment: why `string.split()` when you can just have a string array at no computational cost?

Comment: @Torsten, But don't you need a string as first argument to identify the event? If so it defeats the purpose

Comment: @mix3d You're right defining an array is better and is the way to go for production code. Splitting the string is useful in some cases however where you read lists of words from strings or need to change the strings frequently and want to save typing and reading few characters.

Comment: @Pacerier you're right, this bug got unnoticed for a long time. You can also define a a plain object instead of a switch and use it's keys to listen to the events. Removing event listeners also gets easier if you have an object because you don't need to keep track of the exact listener and just need to pass the object.

Answer (score 9):

Unless your `do_something` function actually does something with any given arguments, you can just pass it as the event handler.

```
var first = document.getElementById('first');
first.addEventListener('touchstart', do_something, false);
first.addEventListener('click', do_something, false);
```

Comment: I just thought there might be a quicker way .. something like:
('touchstart, click', do_something, false)

Comment: @PedroEsperança Nope. I agree, it would be nice to be able to pass an array of strings like `['touchstart','click']` but there's no such thing.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest solution for me was passing the code into a separate function and then calling that function in an event listener, works like a charm.

```
function somefunction() { ..code goes here ..}

variable.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
   somefunction(); // calling function on keyup event
})

variable.addEventListener('keydown', function() {
   somefunction(); //calling function on keydown event
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm new at JavaScript coding, so forgive me if I'm wrong.
I think you can create an object and the event handlers like this:

```js
const myEvents = {
  click: clickOnce,
  dblclick: clickTwice,
};

function clickOnce() {
  console.log("Once");
}

function clickTwice() {
  console.log("Twice");
}

Object.keys(myEvents).forEach((key) => {
  const myButton = document.querySelector(".myButton")
  myButton.addEventListener(key, myEvents[key]);
});
```

```html
<h1 class="myButton">Button</h1>
```

And then `click` on the element.

Comment: PeterJames thank you for the edit. I 'm sorry for my mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

I have a small solution that attaches to the prototype

```
  EventTarget.prototype.addEventListeners = function(type, listener, options,extra) {
  let arr = type;
  if(typeof type == 'string'){
    let sp = type.split(/[\s,;]+/);
    arr = sp;   
  }
  for(let a of arr){
    this.addEventListener(a,listener,options,extra);
  }
};
```

Allows you to give it a string or Array. The string can be separated with a space(' '), a comma(',') OR a Semicolon(';')

Comment: generally, prototype overrides are bad practice (potential future conflict when the specs change), but a perfect function nonetheless

Answer (score 2):

I just made this function (intentionally minified):

```
((i,e,f)=>e.forEach(o=>i.addEventListener(o,f)))(element, events, handler)
```

Usage:

```
((i,e,f)=>e.forEach(o=>i.addEventListener(o,f)))(element, ['click', 'touchstart'], (event) => {
    // function body
});
```

The difference compared to other approaches is that the handling function is defined only once and then passed to every `addEventListener`.

#### EDIT:

Adding a non-minified version to make it more comprehensible. The minified version was meant just to be copy-pasted and used.

```js
((element, event_names, handler) => {

    event_names.forEach( (event_name) => {
        element.addEventListener(event_name, handler)
    })

})(element, ['click', 'touchstart'], (event) => {

    // function body

});
```

Comment: Why minify when showing an example? It only decreases comprehension.

Comment: Edited for comprehensibility. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this:

```js
['focusout','keydown'].forEach( function(evt) {
        self.slave.addEventListener(evt, function(event) {
            // Here `this` is for the slave, i.e. `self.slave`
            if ((event.type === 'keydown' && event.which === 27) || event.type === 'focusout') {
                this.style.display = 'none';
                this.parentNode.querySelector('.master').style.display = '';
                this.parentNode.querySelector('.master').value = this.value;
                console.log('out');
            }
        }, false);
});

// The above is replacement of:
 /*   self.slave.addEventListener("focusout", function(event) { })
      self.slave.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
         if (event.which === 27) {  // Esc
            }
      })
*/
```

Comment: This was the most helpful for me, specially using `['focusout','keydown'].forEach( function(evt)` at the start.

Answer (score 1):

```html
document.getElementById('first').addEventListener('touchstart',myFunction);

document.getElementById('first').addEventListener('click',myFunction);
    
function myFunction(e){
  e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation()
  do_something();
}
```

You should be using `e.stopPropagation()` because if not, your function will fired twice on mobile

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution in which I deal with multiple events in my workflow.

```js
let h2 = document.querySelector("h2");

function addMultipleEvents(eventsArray, targetElem, handler) {
        eventsArray.map(function(event) {
            targetElem.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
        }
    );
}
let counter = 0;
function countP() {
    counter++;
    h2.innerHTML = counter;
}

// magic starts over here...
addMultipleEvents(['click', 'mouseleave', 'mouseenter'], h2, countP);
```

```html
<h1>MULTI EVENTS DEMO - If you click, move away or enter the mouse on the number, it counts...</h1>

<h2 style="text-align:center; font: bold 3em comic; cursor: pointer">0</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it iterating an `Object`. This can work with a single or multiple elements. This is an example:

```
const ELEMENTS = {'click': element1, ...};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(ELEMENTS)) {
    value.addEventListener(key, () => {
        do_something();
    });
}
```

When `key` is the type of event and `value` is the element when you are adding the event, so you can edit `ELEMENTS` adding your elements and the type of event.

Answer (score 0):

Semi-related, but this is for initializing one unique event listener specific per element.

You can use the slider to show the values in realtime, or check the console.
On the `<input>` element I have a `attr` tag called `data-whatever`, so you can customize that data if you want to.

```js
sliders = document.querySelectorAll("input");
sliders.forEach(item=> {
  item.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    console.log(`${item.getAttribute("data-whatever")} is this value: ${e.target.value}`);
    item.nextElementSibling.textContent = e.target.value;
  });
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
span {
  padding-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
* {
  font-size: 12px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="range" min="1" data-whatever="size" max="800" value="50" id="sliderSize">
  <em>50</em>
  <span>Size</span>
  <br>
  <input type="range" min="1" data-whatever="OriginY" max="800" value="50" id="sliderOriginY">
  <em>50</em>
  <span>OriginY</span>
  <br>
  <input type="range" min="1" data-whatever="OriginX" max="800" value="50" id="sliderOriginX">
  <em>50</em>
  <span>OriginX</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//catch volume update
var volEvents = "change,input";
var volEventsArr = volEvents.split(",");
for(var i = 0;i<volknob.length;i++) {
    for(var k=0;k<volEventsArr.length;k++) {
    volknob[i].addEventListener(volEventsArr[k], function() {
        var cfa = document.getElementsByClassName('watch_televised');
        for (var j = 0; j<cfa.length; j++) {
            cfa[j].volume = this.value / 100;
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

'onclick' in the html works for both touch and click event. Here's the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74494605/7134973).

Answer (score 0):

For those whom are looking for a jQuery solution, it could be done like this:

```
$('#selector').on('click touchstart', function() {
    //do something here 
});
```

Or:

```
$('#selector').on('click touchstart', myFunction);
```

Answer (score -1):

This mini javascript libary (1.3 KB) can do all these things

https://github.com/Norair1997/norjs/

```
nor.event(["#first"], ["touchstart", "click"], [doSomething, doSomething]);
```