# Does having multiple unload event functions cause an issue?

Tags: javascript

I have a JS file which has an unload event function, which is pretty important.

However, on one of my pages, I want to call the unload event function inside of it. But I want both the functions to excecute.

Is it possible for both of them to execute? I just don't want one of them to get overridden.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: look at the example at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845678/adding-multiple-event-listeners-to-one-element. Looks like that person had the same question as you did.

Comment: You can always name them different and call both from within an `window.onload` function. Add code and examples and show what your tried.