# how do you add two functions to one event listener

Tags: javascript

how do you add two functions to one event listener

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845678/adding-multiple-event-listeners-to-one-element

Comment: It would help to give more detail, ben lite. Maybe include some code. Show us what you tried. @kmoser gave some great input though. And I'll suggest something else too: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
yourElement.addEventListener('event', function(){
   yourFunction1()
   yourFunction2()
})
```